# how to repair garage concrete threshold

Tags: concrete, floor, garage

[image]

I have a really badly cracked concrete floor at the garage's threshold, looks like the previous owner just slapped concrete on threshold, and it has broken in pieces. What is the right way to fix it?

Also, most of the time I see that garage floor kind of naturally propagates beyond the threshold, up to 20cm or so, and I don't see it in my case. Does it mean the floor is not correctly poured?

Thanks.

Comment: naturally propogates?  sometimes the entrance area slopes down towards the door but that's just to prevent rainwater from flowing in.

Comment: @Jasen, what I meant to say is that in other places I saw a concrete slab goes all the way beyond the threshold, while in my case it stops right where the door closes. It looks like this was build wrong way?

Comment: I don't think this is a simple fix or patch job, I'd say it needs cut out and repoured.

Comment: That job looks like a wheelbarrow job , mixed in a wheelbarrow and poured it was not floated or the shading in the photo looks that way to me.  To do it right I would say it needs to be removed. It looks like there is gravel under the concrete I use welded wire in small areas like that For strength and a good mIx. If you are not putting anything heavy on this no footing is needed. A good mix with some metal should be more than enough for foot traffic.

Comment: @EdBeal, thanks for feedback. Is there a pre-welded wire that can be used, or I'll need to weld it? Generally, you're talking about some kind of wire grid that is put on the surface and concrete is poured over it?

Comment: Yes most home stores carry welded wire as a reenforcement for concrete.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a reinforced foundation beam (footing) under the threshold and reinforcing mesh inside the floor slab, I'm guessing that you are missing both.

fix?  It looks like a do-over to me.

Comment: Footings are not needed for slabs but I would agree on a do over.